# php Bitwise AND return false result

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have problem with AND bitwise opertion on two varialbles when I use variables such as below return correct results, for "lock" = 1, open = 0

```
$ACRel = "00000000000000000000010000000000";

// $STS = "11000000011100000000";  //788224 locked
$STS = "‭11000000001100000000‬";  //787200 open

echo (is_numeric($STS)&is_numeric($ACRel));  // return 1 or 0
```

i received $STS variable in decimal and i use decbin() function to convert:

```
$ACRel = "00000000000000000000010000000000";

//  $sts = decbin(788224);
$sts = decbin(787200); // return 11000000001100000000‬ 

echo (is_numeric($sts)&is_numeric($ACRel));
```

And now i always return 1, decbin in echo return the same value but when I use var_dump i have:

```
$sts = "‭11000000001100000000‬";
/home/vagrant/code/project/pro/calc.php:8:string '‭11000000001100000000‬' (length=26)

$sts = decbin(788224);
/home/vagrant/code/project/pro/calc.php:12:string '11000000001100000000' (length=20)
```

Why length is different, strings look like same ? maybe this is answer ? but I don't know why.

Comment: decbin return a binary variable but $sts = "" return a string variable. They are two different types of variable although the var_dump returns string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the problem you are describing I am seeing two problems here.

### Applying AND bitwise

The first problem I see is, to apply the operation of an AND of bitwise over the value variables described.

But the problem here is, you are ***applying the AND bitwise over the boolean output*** of the method **is_number**. That means that you will always get 1 if they are correct numbers.

A solution here is, you should apply after casting the string as an int: **intval**.

### $STS value with not numeric values

The second problem I see here, is on the first example exposed, the content of this variable **contains non numerical values**:

```
$STS = "‭11000000001100000000‬";  //787200 open
```

There are some characters that are not visible, but if you check with an ASCII tool inspector you can see it: take a look [here](http://asciivalue.com) and [here](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) and copy the value of this variable, you will see that contains non numerical numbers:

```
11000000001100000000U+202C
```

So then, the method **is_numeric** is returning false because *is not recognising this string as a numeric* for that non numeric (not visible) value. And that is the reason why on the first example you get 0.